# In Bootstrap, how do I get my elements to exactly left align?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here below is my code:

```html
<div class="modal-body-scrolled border-primary border-bottom p-0 mt-2">
   <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-12">
         <div class="row ml-0 mr-0">
            <div class="row form-inline col-12 mt-2 mb-2 pt-2 pb-2 m-0">
               <div class="row col-12 mb-2">
                  <div class="col-2 spacer"></div>
                  <div class="col-10 pl-0 d-inline">
                     <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm d-inline" style="width: 40px;"> <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm d-inline"> days </label>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
         <div class="row ml-0 mr-0 mb-3">
            <label for="date" class="col-2 pl-0 justify-content-start align-items-start">Event:</label>
            <select type="field" class="form-control form-control-sm ml-2" style="width:500px" v-model="keyEvent">
               <option value="" disabled selected>(select)</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="row ml-0 mr-0 mb-3">
            <label for="date" class="col-2 pl-0 justify-content-start align-items-start">Date:</label>
            <div class="col-2 pl-0 d-inline">
               <input class="form-control">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm using the standard Bootstrap 12-column layout, with the first column set as `col-2` and the second column set as `col-10`.

I thought that would mean my elements exactly left align but they don't.

How do I get the elements to left align / sit flush with each other?

Comment: Your hierarchy is different in all the elements you should use an equal number of `row` because row has 15px padding.

Comment: @JoykalInfotech Actually, `row` has no padding and a negative margin of `15px`

Comment: yes my bad, it was `col` actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div>
  <div class="row mb-1">
      <div class="col-2"></div>
      <div class="col-10"> <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm d-inline" style="width:             40px;"> <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm d-inline"> days </label>
      </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row mb-1">
    <div class="col-2">
                  <label for="date" class="">Event:</label>

    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
      <select type="field" class="form-control form-control-sm" style="width:500px" v-model="keyEvent">
               <option value="" disabled selected>(select)</option>
            </select>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row mb-1">
    <div class="col-2">
       <label for="date" class="">Date:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
       <input class="form-control" style="width: 140px">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try this structure, this is simple and short, will help you too

Answer (score 1):

Changed the structure:

`col-2` as you mentioned will have the label
`col-8` will have the inputs

> Make sure to wrap `col` in their respective `row`

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body-scrolled">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">
        Label
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm d-inline" style="width: 40px;"> <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm d-inline"> days </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">
        Event:
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
        <select type="field" class="form-control form-control-sm" style="width:500px" v-model="keyEvent">
          <option value="" disabled selected>(select)</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">
        Date:
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
        <div class="col-2 pl-0 d-inline">
          <input class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

we can write it like this with much more simpler way,

just use normal grid classes, you are making your markup too complicate

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container" style="padding: 20px;">

<div class="row mb-3">
  <div class="col-2">
    <label class="label">Label</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-10">
    <input class="form-control" style="width:100px;display:inline-block;" />
    <label class="label" style="display:inline-block;">days</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row mb-3">
  <div class="col-2">
    <label class="label">Label</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-10">
    <select type="field" class="form-control">
      <option value="" disabled selected>(select)</option>
      <option value="" >option 1</option>
    </select>    
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row mb-3">
  <div class="col-2">
    <label class="label">Label</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-10">
    <input class="form-control" style="width:100px;display:inline-block;" />
  </div>
</div>


</div>
```